# grep from first part of a line before delimiter

Tags: shell, grep

I have to grep from this data- test1.txt:

```
1 - Billing_Type
604 - Customer_Name
2 - Contact_Name
3 - Customer_Phone_Number
4 - Contact_Phone_Number
5 - Customer_Type
6 - Reason_Code
7 - CALLE 1
8 - CALLE 2
9 - NUMERO
10 - ID
11 - Service Address
1700001031 - Serial_Number
1700001008 - STB_REF_AP_ID
1700001027 - Smart_Card_ID
```

I am comparing the first part of the file *e.g.* `1700001031`, `1`, `8` etc in a loop from a file and then copying the second part of the file in a variable like the `Serial_Number`, `Billing_Type`, `CALLE 2`.

This is the statement i have used :
sample statement

```
grep -w 1 test1.txt | cut -d'-' -f2 |tr -d ' '
```

but the problem with this statement is that for values 1 and 2 is will output two lines.
for 1 as ID,it will print:

```
Billing_Type
CALLE 1
```

as the ATTR_NAME also contains the word value 1 in 'CALLE 1'.

how do i search in the first part only and get the second without making any extra files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want to use `awk` not `grep` for this:

```
$ awk -F' - ' '$1==1{print $2}' file
Billing_Type
                                                                                                                                            
$ awk -F' - ' '$1==7{print $2}' file
CALLE 1
                                                                                                                                           
$ awk -F' - ' '$1==1700001031{print $2}' file
Serial_Number
```

This does a numeric equality test against the first field `$1` and if the line matches it's prints the second field `$2` using `-` as the field separator.

---

With `GNU Grep` you could do the following but the `awk` approach is definitely the way to go:

```
$ grep -Po '^1\s+-\s+\K.*' file
Billing_Type
                                                                                                                                       
$ grep -Po '^7\s+-\s+\K.*' file
CALLE 1
                                                                                                                                      
$ grep -Po '^1700001031\s+-\s+\K.*' file
Serial_Number
```

This matches the start of string of the string `^` then a given number followed by one or more spaces, a dash and more spaces `\s+-\s+`, `\K` is part of perl compliant regular expressions so don't count on it being widely available, what it does is makes all the previously matched part of the string be forgotten about. Finally we match the rest of the line `.*` and only this is printed thanks to the `-o` option and the `\K`.

---

The approach with `sed` would be to match the line then subsitute the start of the line with an empty string:

```
$ sed -rn '/^1\s/{s/^[0-9]+\s+-\s+//p}' file
Billing_Type
                                                                                                                                            
$ sed -rn '/^7\s/{s/^[0-9]+\s+-\s+//p}' file
CALLE 1
                                                                                                                                        
$ sed -rn '/^1700001031\s/{s/^[0-9]+\s+-\s+//p}' file
Serial_Number
```

Comment: your `awk` method gives me output with blank space. Can it be issue with different terminal?

Comment: `grep` gives me this error. **grep: The -P option is not supported** :(

Comment: If `awk` is giving you output with blank spaces it means your actually file is not the same as your posted file. I clearly state that you need `GNU grep` for the `grep` solution so don't count on `-P` being available. Please confirm your file is of the following format: the line starts with a number followed by a single space, then a hyphen, then a single space, then the part of the line you want printed.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `^` before search ID number to your command

```
grep -w '^1' test1.txt | cut -d'-' -f2 |tr -d ' '
```

Comment: @subodh1989 check sudo_O's edit. it's just matter of requirement of quotes in different terminal. For me it works fine with/without quotes.

Comment: this would be simplest to implement but not workking :(...tried with quotes as well.

Comment: This downside of this solution, beside using 3 commands unnecessarily, it's that is removes all spaces so `grep -w '^7' | ...` will print `CALLE1` not `CALLE 1`

Comment: Completely agree that this is not optimal solution. My intention here was just to mention correction to OP's command